# How to removed the header from a WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm very, very new to WordPress and don't really know what I'm doing yet, but:
I'm working on a website and I would like the ability to use the entire space of the page for "MY" content.  I'd like to completely remove the Header section of the Theme so that I can use that space.

I'm using Thrive Architect as my editor/builder.

How do I completely remove the header so I can add content to that space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to the editor or page builder yout use, but instead it relies on **the theme architecture**. You must look for for [a page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) that would be headerless/footerless (in terms of HTML tags).

If your theme doesn't provide such a template, you could try to add it with a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) help.

1. Create a child theme (using documentation)
2. Activate it. You should have everything exactly as when parent theme is active.
3. Create a page template

   1. You will probably need to create a second header and footer (such `header-empty.php` and `footer-empty.php` see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header), multiple header section. Same apply for footer)
   2. Copy the original header and footer content from `header.php` and `footer.php` you can find in parent theme
   3. Remove all the header/footer HTML stuff you don't need. Please be careful to keep all the `head` section, as well as `wp_head()`/`wp_footer()` call.
   4. Reuse the code for content you could find in other page or another page template (depanding your theme architecture).

All steps above are assuming a correct but generic theme construction. Some themes would be far more complicated than that. That's why I would suggest you to start for [the beginning about theming](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Comment: I read both articles.  I'm not really interested in creating my own theme.
If I create a child theme....how then do I remove the header?

Comment: Also, I could get around the header problem if I could change the height of the header.....how could I do that?

Comment: I completed my answer with general steps. As stated, I cannot go further because it's strongly dependant with you theme architecture.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help.  I'm gonna spend a little time on this...i very much want to learn this.  I have found where some Themes give you a optimal image size for the header.  So I make the image the size they suggest, but the image doesn't respond the way the Theme seems to be designed for.  This is the main reason for me wanting to do this.